# edit a row in a csv file nodejs electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, multidimensional-array

how can I edit one element in a csv file using array

```
//replace the second line with 

var update = [bob,65,old]
```

example

```
jack,15,young
bob,24,young
jill,55,old
doc,22,young
```

edit this with

```
jack,15,young
bob,65,old
jill,55,old
doc,22,young
```

Comment: If the old text and the next text have the same length you can overwrite it. If the lengths are different you have to rewrite everything after the value.

Comment: can you please explain on how to do it exactly

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this. You can open the file with [`fs.open(path[, flags[, mode]], callback)`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback) and write to a specific position with [`fs.write(fd, string[, position[, encoding]], callback)`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_string_position_encoding_callback)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Papaparse (https://www.papaparse.com/) to handle csv files.

**Example:**

```
var csvString = `jack,15,young\nbob,24,young\njill,55,old\ndoc,22,young`
var results = Papa.parse(csvString)
console.log(results)
// {
//     "data": [
//         [
//             "jack",
//             "15",
//             "young"
//         ],
//         [
//             "bob",
//             "24",
//             "young"
//         ],
//         [
//             "jill",
//             "55",
//             "old"
//         ],
//         [
//             "doc",
//             "22",
//             "young"
//         ]
//     ],
//     ...
// }
results.data[1] = ['bob','65','old']
var csv = Papa.unparse(results);
console.log(csv)
// jack,15,young
// bob,65,old
// jill,55,old
// doc,22,young
```

**Note:** you can handle it by hand, but there are a lot of csv types so it is easier to just use a lib.